# How to enable Cloud Watch logs for AWS DMS task?

Tags: aws, aws-aurora

I am creating AWS DMS task for migrating data from GCP SQL server to AWS Aurora MySQL. How can I attach log group which I created?

I could able to enable cloud watch logs for the task but when I click on "View CloudWatch logs" its showing as log group doesn't exit. Details in image -
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your migration task and you can see the `Enable CloudWatch Logs` like below.

[image]

Comment: Where to give log group which I created here? Because If I am not giving anything it showing as "log group" doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow DMS to write logs in CloudWatch, you have to create the `dms-cloudwatch-logs-role` role, as explained here:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dms-cloudwatch-logs-not-appearing/?nc1=h_ls